# comparison of two assemblies and find the changes?

Tags: assemblies

I have two assemblies with the same name. Another one was created after the 15 days of other. How do i what the what are all the changes in the second assemly like method,class,namespace (i,e) everything about the changes in the format of XML file.

Is any tool is avaliable for find the changes in the assemblies ?

Comment: .net assembly? maven assembly? Rocker Arm Assembly?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is called source control repository where your source code is stored. Most of them handle history and allow you to compare differences between commits. If you don't use source control (maybe it's time to start using one) you could [ildasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309387(VS.71).aspx) the assemblies and use your favorite diff tool.